# Moving from Openshift online V2 to Openshift online V3 - alias

Tags: openshift, alias

Im trying to duplicate my PHP/MySQL project currently on Openshift V2 to V3 and am having trouble getting it to work.

In V2, you had to setup an alias for your public URL (mysite.com) and the openshift URL (http://example-xxapp.rhcloud.com/).

The CNAME is set with my hosting provider. It works great using Openshift V2.

So, how do you setup the equivalent (alias) in the Openshift Online V3 platform?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: For a start, what OpenShift cluster are you using? If you are using OpenShift Online Starter you can't add custom domain names to applications. If not on Starter, you need to create a new route for the service and plug your custom domain name in as the hostname for that route.

Comment: I'm on the starter package.  I'm just redirecting/or setting the CNAME on my domain provider (1and1) that points to the public host name created by the route on openshift v3.  I can hit the homepage and can even run the php script from a web browser, but for some reason I get a server error 500 when trying to run the php script from my IOS app.  So, I'm not trying to create a custom domain on Openshift but rather directing my domain name to the public name created in the route.  This works fine on openshift V2 with the use of the alias setting.  Am I missing something?

Comment: If you are getting a 500 error, then look at the error logs for the pod to see what error your code may be logging. The OpenShift routing system wouldn't return a 500 and so that must be coming from your application code.

Answer (score 1):

As Graham mentioned, in OpenShift Online 3 Starter custom domain names are not supported (see [pricing page](https://www.openshift.com/pricing/index.html#online-plan-comparison)).

For the OpenShift Online Pro tier:

1. Create a route with your custom domain name
2. Point the CNAME for your custom domain to `https://elb.b9ad.pro-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com`

For reference, `b9ad` is the router shard in use on `pro-us-east-1` (for all routes created). The router shard will be different on other Pro regions when they become available. The `elb` is an arbitrary subdomain that simply ensures your CNAME routes to the OpenShift Online cluster to be resolved (I prefer using `elb` because technically you're pointing your CNAME at the elastic load balancer for the OpenShift Online cluster).

Answer (score 0):

You will get a public hostname in v3 (called a route) similar the rhcloud.com address on v2.